# Which song, using just one instrument or one voice, has charted the highest in the US Billboard Hot 100?

Tags: chart-success

The song can have one instrument or one voice, but NOT both (in other words, either a solo instrumental, or a solo acapella voice), and must be performable without multi-tracking. I imagine the classical charts contain such recordings, like piano performances, but what the US Billboard Hot 100?

Comment: But I'd be surprised if there weren't in fact _multiple No. 1 hits_ that used only voice and either piano or guitar. Then again, what do I know of pop music...

Answer (score 3):

My candidate would be "Mercedes Benz" from Janis Joplin.  Problem with the billboard is that it was the B side of the "Cry Baby" single (placed #42) and the last recorded track (she died few days later) on the LP "Pearl" (placed #1) so it's hard to give it a rating of its own.  It's been one of the more iconic performances and a lot of other singers made cover versions, though.